# What are some common patterns to ensure persistence of data for Rails models across multiple systems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, persistence, rails-activerecord

Let us say we have the following scenario:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :throw_after_save
  after_commit :throw_after_commit

  private
    def throw_after_save
      raise "raising on after_save"
    end

    def throw_after_commit
      raise "raising on after_commit"
    end
end

class MyController < ApplicationController
  def callback
    begin
      MyModel.new(params).save
    rescue
      flash[:alert] = "Failed persisting to external system. Try again."
      Airbrake.notify(
        error_class: "External System Persistence",
        error_message: "External System Persistence: Failed to persist data",
        parameters: params
      )
    end

    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

We get a callback from an external system (where the user fills out some data and creates a temporary set of attributes for an account).

Let us assume that we want to persist some data locally after the callback to us is made. After this data is persisted, we want to make a call to the external system to complete the account creation process. The external system shall return a result informing us of success with some additional data that we need to persist locally. We also know that in some *exceptional* cases, persistence on the remote system will not occur successfully (let us say system is not available, or something goes wrong on their end).

The objective is to capture external persistence exceptions as well as successes and act accordingly. In the case of successes, everything is hunky dory: the additional data is stored locally, the `redirect_to root_path` happens. In the case of exceptions, however, we'd like to indicate this to the user (perhaps set a `flash[:alert]` to be displayed in the view).

We had tried to use `ActiveRecord::Callbacks` to throw an exception from the model `after_save` and `after_commit` and handle that exception at the controller by setting an alert and possibly passing the exception to some exception notification system (like Airbrake). In the case of `after_save`, the exception is thrown by the model and caught by the controller, but the record is not saved (and we have the requirement of storing the partial data even in the case of exceptions with the external system - this is not acceptable). In the case of `after_commit`, the exception is *not* thrown and picked up by the controller, but the partial record is persisted. This means we cannot notify the user of the exception (unless we implement some notification pushing mechanism - which is overkill).

As it turns out, we *can* set errors on the model on `after_save`, which is nice. But, is this a *good* general pattern to handle this sort of scenario?

Comment: This seems like it might be a really useful resource...
http://rubysource.com/ddd-for-rails-developers-part-1-layered-architecture/

Reading through now.

Also:
http://railsconf2012.com/sessions/50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a lot of options in there. Since the logic itself of what you are asking is complex, I'd move the code to save the record to somewhere else (maybe a class method or another class, representing a service) and when someone wanted to save this specific object it would have to go through this service model.

For instance:

```
class MyModelPersistenceService

    def save_model( model )
      result = model.save
      if result
        call_external_service
      end
    end 

end
```

[Services](http://stochastyk.blogspot.com.br/2008/05/domain-services-in-domain-driven-design.html) are not that common in Ruby/Rails projects but they are a nice fit for this kind of usage (and abusing AR callbacks usually leads to hard to test objects).

Comment: Service pattern makes sense. It would encapsulate the external service persistence, vs relying on the model itself to handle that. The only "issue" with this of course is that it breaks the standard Rails pattern of `instance = Model.new(attributes)`, followed by `instance.save`. I am still interested whether it might be doable to encapsulate the logic gracefully inside the model itself to avoid breaking out of the common Rails patterns. Mostly, I am interested in this from a purely informational standpoint.

Comment: You shouldn't be afraid of jumping out of the rails common patterns, many of those patterns are ok for simple apps but really bad when they get complex, the spaghetti callbacks is one of such examples, once you get too much, your AR code seems to do too much magic and becomes hard to test and to reason about it. There are many other solutions to this that will be different than the Rails default and this is ok, they're different solutions to the same problems.